# Using Atlassian Sourcetree, is it possible to see what changes will be pulled from the remote repository before executing the pull?

Tags: git, version-control, atlassian-sourcetree

Without resorting to the command line, is there a way within the Sourcetree application to see diffs of the changes that would be pulled from a remote repository prior to executing the pull? If so, how?

I know that if I go to the Repository menu and choose Refresh Remote Status, that will update the Pull icon in Sourcetree and show how far ahead of me the remote branch is, measured by the number of commits. But, I'd like to actually see diffs comparing those changes to what I currently have in the local branch before I choose to pull the changes.

Comment: The question is not a duplicate and should not have been closed. The question is specifically about doing this in Atlassian Sourcetree GUI. I don't use git on the command line. A question that provides a command line-based answer is not an answer that describes the particulars of accomplishing this inside the Sourcetree application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to:

1. Fetch all branches (NOT pull)
2. Inspect the history of the remote branch you are interested in.